# Email addresses visible to bots in public repositories?

Tags: github

Do I have to worry about my email address being picked up by bots when it is in the documentation of code that is in a public repository like GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Github, select any project at random, and start clicking links until you get to a source file that is displayed directly in the browser.

Conclusion: it is possible for your email address in a source file posted to Github to be picked up by a bot.  Whether it's likely or not is another story.

Note that the authors of jQuery UI [are not squeamish about putting their email addresses up on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/AUTHORS.txt).